# Dompdf css not working on live server but its working in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

Hi i got problem in dompdf.. I want to display my invoice page by using css. In localhost css, styles, images are working fine but in live server CSS is not supported, I enabled DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE but still its not working, actually i developed this code in codeigniter framework.. kindly help me.. My coding is..

Php Code: Controller

```
public function dompdf($id="") {

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $page_data['po_id'] = $id;
    // Load all views as normal
    $this->load->view('admin/welcome_message',$page_data);
    // Get output html
    $html = $this->output->get_output();

    // Load library
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

    // Convert to PDF
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->set_paper('sra3','landscape');
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $this->dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));

}
```

dompdf_config.inc.php

Here i have enabled DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE

```
def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
```

Comment: What is the error, have you included the library right (uppercase name), ...

Comment: @joerg Yes i have included everything, css file is not supported in live server

Comment: Is it a path problem?

Comment: @joerg - No already i checked that

Comment: What's about the encoding of the css file?

Comment: @joerg - i have added like this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89575/discussion-between-sathish-and-joerg).

Comment: Might help to see a sample of the HTML produced. More than likely it's a path problem. Since you're using `load_html` dompdf looks for external files that do not include a FQDN either relative to the executing script or file system root.

Comment: @BrianS - Yes I used load_html `$this->dompdf->load_html($html);`

Comment: Can you reference your CSS via the web server (e.g. http://example.com/styles.css)? If not you'll need to tweak the path so that it points to the correct location. If you're having trouble finding the correct relative path you could try an absolute path from the root of the filesystem.